# Storing Service bus connection string locally

Tags: service, azureservicebus

I have a web app hosted in azure posting topics to a service bus queue. The connection string is stored in a secure vault and all is good.

I would like a number of windows services running worker threads on various customers local machines to pick up their own messages, they will then perform a set of tasks based on the message they receive.

How do you secure the service bus connection string for the windows service? Appsettings?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple options built into Windows [Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/accessing-credential-manager-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0), which is a more general app for storing passwords on a machine, and the [Windows Data Protection API](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/bf374083-626f-3446-2a9d-3f6077723a60) which helps with encryting/decrypting passwords you can store somewhere on disk. Both make use of the user's password to encrypt and decrypt the passwords.

What I would suggest as an added layer of protection is to issue the customers an Service Principal ID/Secret instead of the Service Bus queue connection string with read access to that particular secret in your Key Vault. It unlinks the dependency between the Service Bus connection string and your customers, i.e. you can rotate your keys without contacting each one, and if you issue individual Service Principals you'll be able to revoke access easily- adding the Service Principals to a security group and giving the group access to the Key Vault will make management much easier.

Comment: Thanks, i thought you could only use service principals if the app was hosted. The client windows service is not hosted it runs locally.

Comment: I have added an application identity in azure ad, and given access to the service bus. Using a client is, token Id and secret I can connect to the service bus no problem but..... surely I don’t store client, token and secret in the app.config?

Comment: Managed Identity is only available within Azure. Service Principals can be used from anywhere. The App Id isn't as important, but you would want to put the secret in Credential Manager or use the Windows Data Protection API same as if you were to use the connection string.

Comment: in your comment above about unlinking the dependency. Do you mean use a app (client) ID, tenant id and secret value to Access a keyvault that contains the queues connection string (i.e. sas endpoint)? or something else, im still struggling to get this to work, i was thinking certificates?

Comment: Correct. You can also setup Key Vault access with a certificate if you would like- you can still use the service principal -> key vault option as you can authenticate that with either a secret or cert: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-service-principal-auth#client-certificate-credential

Comment: yes but even if  you use keyvault you still need to store credentials locally to access them, a client id, secret or certificate. so how do  you secure those :)